# How can I best respond to endless additional questions in the comments and aggressive edits to an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, specific-edit

A few days ago I was answering [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69068239/4420129) where implementation with `python-requests` was impossible, so I suggested [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) and gave a short implementation of his code. The question asker has since been asking comments on my answer including troubleshooting various Selenium issues, including environment issues, and has even made [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29826838) to my answer with his/her debug information to an answer to another question he/she had asked in the comments!

What should I do in this case? Merging it with the original question would not be good practice as the question has completely changed, and I feel that answering any more will eventually lead me to completing his/her whole project without my answer even getting accepted.

Comment: Minor point: I think you voted to close this question. In the future, if you get a suggestion as a duplicate that you agree with, you can approve the suggestion (there should be a pop-up that you see), and that will instantly close the question.

Comment: Just disengage as soon as possible - we used to call those "help [blood-sucking creates of the night]" but, apparently, this is now considered "unkind" regardless of how true this assertion is. You aren't getting paid by the OP, so feel free to not follow up on any of their requests, especially if they move goal posts